# Adding bits x32 mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to add 2 strings of bits in a function and i cannot get it to work... any suggestions? here is my code below:

```
$a0, "11111111111100000001111111111110"    #= -4064

$a1, "00000000001000111000000000000010"   # = 9088

$a2, resultSpace 
$a3, representation                #one's or two's complement

li $t4, 0 #carry flag 

lb $t0, 32($a0)
lb $t1, 32($a1)

move $t5, $a0

loop: 
lb $t0, 32($a0)
lb $t1, 32($a1)


add $t3, $t0, $t1


sb $t3, 32($a2)

sub $a2, $a2, 1 
sub $a0, $a0, 1
sub $a1, $a1, 1 


addi $t4, $t4, 1 # increments 
bne $t4, 32, loop
```

Comment: there's nothing called "x32 mips assembly"

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few pointers.

1. You're confusing *bits* with *ASCII characters '0' and '1'*. If you add '0' and '1' you get not '1' but 'a' (because '0' is character 48, '1' is character 49, and 'a' is character 97).
2. You're starting by looking at offset 32 in each string. But the strings are 32 characters long, so the valid offsets into them are 0..31, so the very first thing you do is to read off the end of the input data.
3. You're not using the carry flag in the addition. Neither are you doing anything to check for carries when you add bits.
4. You are, however, using the register that you claim is the carry flag as a loop counter.

I'm very far from being a MIPS assembler expert so these two may be wrong:

1. Are you missing some instructions at the start of your code? I mean, can you really say just `$a2, resultSpace` or do you need `la $a2, resultSpace` or something of the kind?
2. Is there a bne-immediate pseudoinstruction? Because I'm pretty sure there isn't an actual bne-immediate instruction; the `bne` instruction in the MIPS instruction set expects to be given two registers rather than a register and an immediate value.

Comment: i was thinking about this in hex soo if i took 0 + 0 which is 0x30 + 0x30 would give me 0x60 right? that is not in anyway 0 so i subtract 0x30. Same as it would 0x31 + 0x30 = 0x61 and subtract 0x30 would give me 0x31 which would be a 1...that being said that does work out.. the only problem that i am having is with the carry bit. So how should i set up a carry bit register? I apologize about the resultSpace.. the coding is long and i didn't add that into my copy so here is what result space actually looks like:

Comment: resultSpace: .space 33
that is just what is in my $a2 register

Comment: Yup, subtracting 0x30 is the way to turn digit-adding into bit-adding. Carry bit: have a register that contains 0 (no carry) or 1 (carry). Add it in along with your two data bits. The result will be 0, 1, 2, or 3. Bit 1 (i.e., (result>>1)&1) is the new carry.